# ASP.NET Core Web API Response caching with expiration header

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to cache the responses of my web api UNTIL a specific time and not FOR a specific time. For that I would like to use some sort of expiration header. As of right now I use the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching" package with the "ResponseCache" Attribute on my Actions like this:

`[ResponseCache(Duration = 50)]`

The reason why I would like to use an expiration is that the api only provides GET Methods and the data is static (with a refresh one time a day). Is there a possibility to implement something like this?:

```
[ResponseCache(Expires = 00:00AM)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not with the current state of the ResponseCache attribute in .net core. Hopefully it'll be improved in the future. Maybe you could submit an issue on their repo so someone will know to code it & submit a pull request?

There is a community-built alternative that gives you the feature you need.
https://github.com/KevinDockx/HttpCacheHeaders https://www.nuget.org/packages/Marvin.Cache.Headers

Couldn't you also set the Duration to 60 * 60 * 24 (#SecondsInADay) ? Or does your data need to refresh at an exact time during the day?

Another option would be to modify the response context headers directly. This is typically done in a custom middleware.

Something like this:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();

    context.Response.Headers["headerName"] = "headerValue";
});
```

Unforunately, it gets a bit trickier. The response headers can't be modified after the response body has already been written, even if it hasn't been transmitted to the server.

Most middleware's get around this by "shimming"/"wrapping" the response body's stream.

```
public class ShimmedResponseContext
  {
    public HttpContext _httpContext { get; }
    private Stream _originalResponseStream { get; set; }
    private MemoryStream _shimmedResponseStream { get; set; }

    public ShimmedResponseContext(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
      _httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    public void ShimResponseStream()
    {
      _originalResponseStream = _httpContext.Response.Body;
      _shimmedResponseStream = new MemoryStream();
      _httpContext.Response.Body = _shimmedResponseStream;
    }

    public void UnshimResponseStream()
    {
      _shimmedResponseStream.Position = 0;
      _shimmedResponseStream.CopyTo(_originalResponseStream);
      _httpContext.Response.Body = _originalResponseStream;
    }
  }

  app.Use(async (context, next) =>
  {
    var shimmedContext = new ShimmedResponseContext(context);
    shimmedContext.ShimResponseStream();

    await next();

    context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "public,expires=[your chosen date/time]";

    shimmedContext.UnshimResponseStream();
  });
```

Also, make sure you register this middleware before app.UseMVC(); in your Startup.cs Configure method, because Middleware's run in order & only previously registered Middlewares can hijack the response after a later Middelware has written it.